# Draw custom polygon on map for heatmap in python from table of lat/long points?

Tags: python, plotly, geopandas, cartopy

I have a panda that has a column for zip_code, sub_region, index, lat, long, center_lat, center_long. Where the subregion is a contiguous sub area of a zipcode, the index is the order of the lat/long point to create the polygon, the lat and long columns are for each point and the center lat and center long are the center for each sub region. I am trying to make a heatmap for each subregion. I've been digging into plotly, cartopy, and geopandas but so far haven't been able to make this work. Does anyone have any ideas or thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Providing some example code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(zip_shape.latitude, zip_shape.longitude)]
df1 = zip_shape.drop(['latitude', 'longitude'], axis=1)
gdf1 = GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=geometry).sort_values(['zip_code','subregion','indx'])

gdf1['geometry']=gdf1['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.coords[0])
df2 = gdf1.groupby(['zip_code','subregion'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: Polygon(x.tolist())).reset_index()

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry = 'geometry')
gdf.to_file('Geo1.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')

gdf2.plot()
```